# Не знаю как настроить объект для кода, который должен перемещать объект курсором при зажатой скм (unity)

Tags: unity3d, координаты, мышь, элементы-управления, chatgpt

Код был написан chatGPT, а сам я новичок, который мало что понимает. Насколько я понимаю данный код нужно добавить к объекту, как компонент и добавить к этому объекту 2д коллайдер, эти приколы сделал, но видимо этого оказалось мало, пробовал добавлять ригбади 2д, тоже не помогло (В ригбади 2д выставлял static, kinematic и dynamic) Unity на скрипт ошибок не дал, проворачивал всё это с объектом square (он был не в canvas)

```css
using UnityEngine;

public class DragObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isDragging = false;
    private Vector3 offset;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            isDragging = true;
            offset = transform.position - GetMouseWorldPos();
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = GetMouseWorldPos();
            transform.position = new Vector3(mousePos.x + offset.x, transform.position.y, mousePos.z + offset.z);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPos()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            return hit.point;
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо